# How to get the column name with a specific string?

Tags: shell-script, awk

I want to get the top PID and Command which is taking the CPU > 90% on the server. I want the CPU% in a variable. I have tried it using the below ps command.

```
ps -eo pid,cmd,%cpu --sort=-%cpu | head -2
  PID CMD                         %CPU
  987 dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/nul 63.6
```

I am trying it using AWK but It's getting me with the wrong information as it is showing dd command as a different column.

Any way to get the cpu %

Comment: Why are you using options like `pid, cmd` when you only need the `%CPU`. What is your final goal?

Comment: I want all of them in a particular variable. So that I can use them later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command will give you the %CPU:

```
ps -eo pid,cmd,%cpu --sort=-%cpu | head -2| tail -1 | awk '{print $NF}'
```

- `tail -1` - will provide the last line, which hold the actual number
- `awk 'print $NF}'` will print the last element in the that line

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach to get the *top* cpu %:

```
ps -eo %cpu --sort=-%cpu --no-headers | head -1
```

---

> `--no-headers`
>      Print no header line at all